# Sql Server 2014 - Update to windows 10 and can't connect to the Local Server

Tags: sql-server, server, sql-server-2014

Recently I updated my Windows from 8 to 10 and suddenly my SQL Server 2014 stopped working. When I open the Management Studio and try to connect to the Server (local) i obtain the following error:

[image: Obtained Message]

Does any of you had similar problems? Before updating the Windows everything was running just fine.

Comment: Had no problems what so ever (upgraded from 8.1 to 10 with MSSQL2012 and MSSQL2014 installed and both are fine). Did you check if the service is running?

Comment: Run SQL server installation file - setup.exe. Then under maintenance tab you will find a repair option. Try that,hope that will help - I have faced the same problem after updating to windows 10.

Comment: @TiagoNeto Good to know! You can upvote my comment as helpful :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I had the same problem after upgrading from Windows 8.1 Pro to Windows 10 Pro. I was able to resolve it as follow:

1. Control Panel
2. Administrative Tools
3. Services
4. The **SQL Service Browser** was Disabled
5. Right click and select **Properties**
6. Change the Startup type to **Automatic (Delayed Start)**
7. Click to **Start** button to start the service
8. And off you go. This should resolve the issue.

Comment: +1 not exactly how it solved my problem, but somehow it gave me direction on how to solve the issue for me. i'm using MSSQLSERVER2016 and I just needed to start the right windows service.

Answer (score 8):

I just had the same issue after upgrading my laptop from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10; however, my solution was slightly different to the one suggested already, I had to:

1) Control Panel
2) Services
3) Right-click, Start, SQL Server service

I had to do this for all the SQL versions I have installed (08R2 up to 14). Somehow the upgrade stopped and didn't restart the SQL service.

Comment: true, this has ressolved my issue too, the SQL Server service was stopped, I just had to restart it and i could login normally

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered the same issue upgrading from Windows 7.  First thing I did was open the SQL SERVER MANAGER CONSOLE and ensure that the server was still running.  After seeing that it was, I restarted it, and that fixed the problem.

I personally would try these simple steps first... never know could be that easy.

- Side note - if you have trouble finding the SQL Manager Console in your Programs list like I did, you can likely find it in your C:Windows/SysWOW folder (open file named SQLServerMananger##.msc).

Comment: I started having the same issue after an automatic update from windows and this resolved my issue. Sql Server (SQLEXPRESS) under Sql Server Services was in 'stopped' state so I started it and I was able to connect to my server again. Thanks!