# SQL Server problems when migrating from Win7 to Win10

Tags: sql-server, windows-10

I migrated a program I wrote in Win7, VS2013 to Win10 machine. The program is failing with message:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

In Win7 machine I see 3 services runnig: MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS, SQLBrowser, SQL Writer

In Win10: SQL Writer only, and I don't see any other services related to SQL Server.

On Win10 machine I downloaded VS2015 and I see it installed Microsoft SQL Server programs from 2012 to 2016.

In Win10 I wrote a test program to open database and I am getting the same error message.

My question: is SQL Writer the SQL server? How to start SQL local server in Win10?

Any ideas where to look for solution?

---

I installed SQL Server Express 2014 from [SQL Sever Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299) and now everything is working, but as professional malcontent I am not satisfied with the solution.

First – when under VS2015 I develop a program which is using SQL Server – is it too much to ask from VS2015 at least to warn me that I need to install SQL Server to run this program?

Second - is it possible in Visual Studio to develop a program which is using a database and to migrate it to a computer without SQL Server installed? It is possible in Android – I wrote an app which is using SQLite database and this program will run on any Android device, because SQLite is automatically part of the app.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32026219/sql-server-2014-update-to-windows-10-and-cant-connect-to-the-local-server

Comment: The accepted answer in @FLICKER 's comment worked for me a few months ago when I went through it.  Basically, go to Windows Services, find SQL Server and set it to Automatic startup.

Comment: I don't think @Zalek Bloom has installed SQL Server. He has only installed Visual Studio which installs localdb and not SQL Server Express.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your SQL Server service is running.  Search for 'Services', open windows Services, scroll down to SQL Server and check the status.  Right click and Start.

You should be able to start it manually, but open the properties and set the startup type to Automatic and that should take care of it from then on out.

When I migrated to W10, I had to do this one or two times with restarts between before it stuck.  Been good since then.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the localdb instance. VS 2015 is installing a localdb instance which is a bit similar to SQL Server Express. Open Visual Studio and click on View --> SQL Server Object Explorer. You will be able to see the localdb instances that VS2015 has created. The main difference between localdb and SQL Server Express is that localdb does not use a service to run. That's why you don't see a SQL Server service. Try downloading the free version of SSMS from here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx and try to connect to the instance that appears in your VS2015 SQL Server Object Explorer window. Normally it should look something like this: (localdb)\ProjectsV12.

Answer (score 0):

After posting my answer I continued to read about SQL server and to clarify for myself and maybe for others here are detail explanations what happened:

There are 2 kinds of databases:
service-based database is when the database is stored on a server. To access the database, you need to have the SQL Server service running. The extension of the file is .mdf

"local database" is a database that is stored on the local PC where an application resides. There is no need to install a server to access an SDF database
The extension of the file is .sdf

In my application the database file has the extension .mdf, it means it requires service-base database, like SQL Server Express.

It was my stupidity - sorry for insulting VS2015 – it is a great program!